# C# Unicode (Japanese Characters)

Tags: c#, unicode, console

I have a Japanese final coming up soon, so to help me study I made a program to help me study. But, I can't seem to get VS2008 to display any Unicode in the Console. This is a sample I used to see if I could display Unicode:

```
    string diancai = new string(new char[]{ '\u70B9','\u83DC' });

    Console.Write(diancai[0] + " " + diancai[1]);
```

Output is:

```
    ? ?
```

Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Go to your command prompt and try a command "chcp"

It should be like this

```
C:\> chcp
現在のコード ページ: 932
```

932 is japanese, If code page is not correct or if your windows does not support, It can't display it in console.

I can run yours in mine, its display following chars, mine is japanese windows.

```
点 菜
```

So, For your case, I recommand you to try with GUI program instead of console

Comment: I did it and this was the result:

     C:\> chcp
     Active code page: 437

Any chance I can change it to 932?

Comment: Try `chcp 932`, and try copy paste "点 菜", if you can't see that, its mean you cannot do that. try with GUI.

Comment: OH I see...Umm this might be too much to ask, but can you please give me a sample code, showing me how to display characters using a GUI window? This is my first time programming in C# and my final is coming up soon.

Comment: And I've been searching for an answer all day today with no luck.

Comment: I prsume you're using an english version of Wondows? it doesn't work here either...

Comment: Yeah, its mean, your windows doesnot support it, for GUI, In Visual C# windows, there is option for New Project for `C# Windows Applications`, So just go ahead and try it, I assumed you know C# Language itself.

Comment: so there is no way of using UTF8 in console? im trying with this word: "Đức" but it's not working

Answer (score 2):

There are two conditions that must be satisfied in order for this to work:

1. The console's output encoding must be able to represent Japanese characters
2. The console's font must be able to render them

Condition 1 should be fairly simple to deal with; just set [`System.Console.OutputEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.outputencoding.aspx) to an appropriate [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx), such as a [`UTF8Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.aspx). (Of course, this won't work on Windows 9x, since that doesn't really support encodings or Unicode. But you aren't using that, now, are you?)

Satisfying condition 2 is a bit more involved:

1. First, an appropriate font must be installed on the user's system. If there aren't any installed yet, the user will have to install some, perhaps by:

   - Opening `intl.cpl` ("Regional and Language Options" in the Control Panel on Windows XP in English)
   - Going to the "Languages" tab
   - Enabling "Install files for East Asian languages"
   - Clicking "OK"
2. Actually getting the console to use such a font seems to be fairly hairy; see the question: [How to display japanese Kanji inside a cmd window under windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780378/how-to-display-japanese-kanji-inside-a-cmd-window-under-windows) for more about that.

Answer (score 1):

I use Windows XP english version.
But I set my OS so it can show Japanese characters.

For Windows XP this is the step:

1.Control Panel -> Regional and Language Options -> Advanced

2.Choose Japanese.

3.Choose code page conversion tables for language do you use.

4.Push OK button

5.Restart your computer.

I tried to use "chcp" command on command prompt.

It display: Active code page 932