# Display non standard characters in console window

Tags: c++, unicode, character-encoding, visual-studio-2013, windows-console

I want to display non standard characters using the console window - anything similar to Japanese/Chinese/whatever will do. I tried using unicode characters, but the console window displays them as question marks.

Also tried setting the windows locale using

```
char *locale;
locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "ja_JP")
```

or

```
char *locale;
locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "")
```

Neither of which worked nor mean anything to me
These characters, which I believe are kano (?), would be ideal, but I'm really not fussy

あかさたないきしちにうくすつぬえけせてねおこそとのはまやらわひみりをふむゆるんへめれ

Comment: Ah, tell it to the Japanese that they're not standard :-)

Comment: In the properties of your cmd icon, you can specify a font. I guess that not unicode might not be fully implemetned by these. You should also have a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109024/how-to-make-unicode-charset-in-cmd-exe-by-default

Comment: @Christophe still get question marks, and i have no intention of changing it at system level

Comment: I understand. I had also a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780378/how-to-display-japanese-kanji-inside-a-cmd-window-under-windows . There are some hints on how to do it over registry control. In one of the comment, it's reminded to make sure that unicode ouput functions (wprintf(), wcout, ...) are used.

Comment: i would prefer to avoid editing registry keys... wprintf and wcout print nothing to the console window. I can print using `cout << \u001A;` as far as 001f, they are the only ones that dont display as a question mark