# Convert integer to Chinese numerals in c#

Tags: c#, internationalization

I would like to convert an integer to Chinese numerals, I have tried the code below but all it outputs is the character "3" and not the Chinese equivalent. Can someone tell me if this is possible in c#?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("zh-CN", false);
        ci.NumberFormat.DigitSubstitution = DigitShapes.NativeNational;

        int value = 3;

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(ci, "{0}", value));
    }
```

I've also tried it with value.ToString(ci), but get the same result.

Comment: This should be a problem with the `Console` code page, take a look at this [so question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780378/how-to-display-japanese-kanji-inside-a-cmd-window-under-windows).

Comment: Check out the Microsoft documentation on DigitSubstitution: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.digitsubstitution(v=vs.110).aspx .  It mentions that is reserved for future use and not currently used.

Comment: Also, check out the ci.NumberFormat.NativeDigits property.  It contains an array of the Western 0-9 digits and their interpretation in the culture you defined.  You will see that the array contains regular numbers.

Comment: Yes, I spotted the MS page regarding future use. Unfortunately I cannot find another mechanism to do the conversion. Apparently simple digit substitution doesn't work with Chinese as it is more complex that that.

Comment: Regarding the font comment and console, if I put a break point and examine the output of string.Format(...) in debug it is still only showing "3" and not the Chinese equivalent. string abc = string.Format(ci, "{0}", value); abc = "3"