# CMD/Batch - Deleting a file with UTF-8 Characters in the filename (ex. Japanese, Chinese characters)

Tags: batch-file, utf-8

I'm trying to remove a list of files that I have in a textfile.
I'm essentially trying to do this:

```
del 二月.mp3 /f
```

It doesn't seem to work because of the UTF-8 characters. I searched around a lot and haven't found a way to get around this.
Anyone got a solution for this?

I'm trying to delete 10,000+ files from a folder using a text file list I have of those files. The files each have Japanese characters in the name.

Thank you :)

Comment: `rm` is not a standard command in a Windows batch file, is there some alternative environment that you haven't reported in your question?

Comment: make sure your editor is using UTF8 encoding when creating your BAT file. Or use the short name of the file, that you can obtain with `dir /x`

Comment: I meant to write del instead of rm.
I made sure my bat file is in UTF-8 encoding.
I'm trying to delete 10,000+ files from a list, and the files have Japanese characters in them, so I have to use some sort of scripting to do it.

Comment: Have a look on [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780378/how-to-display-japanese-kanji-inside-a-cmd-window-under-windows)

Answer (score 2):

Following batch script and sample text file show that `CMD`/Batch is capable to work with file names from [`UCS-2` Unicode subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) **providing that**

- both *`bat` script* and *`txt` file list* are saved in [`UTF-8` character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), and
- the script is run under [`UTF-8` active console code page](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html), or (better) sets active console code page to `UTF-8` itself, see `chcp 65001` command.

(*CJK Ideographs* and Central European *accented Latin letters* are used in following examples, both explicitly used in a batch command and read from a saved list of such file names.)

Note that the *weird* first line in `bat` script (`@foo.bar >NUL 2>&1`) is there as `cmd` is `UTF-8` aware but **isn't *BOM* aware** (cf [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)):

- if script is saved without BOM then this line would be performed with no effect while
- if script is saved with BOM then this line would be listed prefixed with some character(s), see `ï»¿` in the following output.

Note that the first line in `txt` file list is empty for the same reason (`cmd` isn't *BOM* aware) so `for /F` loop would ignore this empty line if BOM is not present otherwise an attempt to do something with such file raises `File Not Found` error (this message could be suppressed using `2>NUL`).

**`42030220.bat` script**:

```
@foo.bar >NUL 2>&1
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
chcp 65001
echo next command: for /F "usebackq delims=" %%G …
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%G in ("D:\bat\files\unASCII\42030220.txt") do (
    dir /B /S "%%~G"
    REM
    REM use `del /S "%%~G"` instead of `dir /B /S "%%~G"` 
)
echo next command: dir /B /S /A:-D "D:\bat\Unusual Names\CJK\中文(繁體)\*"
dir /B /S /A:-D "D:\bat\Unusual Names\CJK\中文(繁體)\*"
```

**`42030220.txt` file list** (note leading empty line):

```
 
二月.mp3
ěščřžýáíé.txt
装备女印度舞娘时装上衣.rtf
```

**Output**:

```
d:\bat> d:\bat\SO\42030220.bat

d:\bat> ï»¿@foo.bar  1>NUL 2>&1
Active code page: 65001
next command: for /F "usebackq delims=" %G …
File Not Found
d:\bat\Unusual Names\CJK\中文(繁體)\二月.mp3
d:\bat\UnASCII Names\ěščřžýáíé.txt
d:\bat\Unusual Names\CJK\中文(繁體)\装备女印度舞娘时装上衣.rtf
next command: dir /B /S /A:-D "D:\bat\Unusual Names\CJK\中文(繁體)\*"
D:\bat\Unusual Names\CJK\中文(繁體)\chinese traditional.txt
D:\bat\Unusual Names\CJK\中文(繁體)\二月.mp3
D:\bat\Unusual Names\CJK\中文(繁體)\装备女印度舞娘时装上衣.rtf

d:\bat>
```