# Windows Console Output from Waifu2x-caffe unintelligible

Tags: windows, batch-file, runtime-error

I am using Waif2x to upscale a series of images, but I am having a problem with the command I am running. I would try to troubleshoot it myself, yet I can't not make use of the error output. It reads:

```
âGâëü[: âéâfâïâtâ@âCâïé¬èJé»é▄é╣é±é┼é╡é╜
```

I think it is in Japanese as evidenced by Waifu2x's Github page. I also believe it is the same everytime, yet I cant know for sure.  I am using a English Computer, and I am also a English speaker, so I really need to know what it is in English or something I can Google translate. 
I have already tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780378/how-to-display-japanese-kanji-inside-a-cmd-window-under-windows) as evidenced by looking at the regedit, where `Name=00, Data=Consolas`.

Regarding my specific problem, the Command I am typing into cmd is

```
waifu2x-caffe-cui -i "C:\Users\Christian\workspace\CodeLyokoUpscaleing\bin\480Frames" -e png -l png -m noise_scale -d 16 -h 1440 -n 1 -p cudnn -c 256 -b 1 --auto_start 1 --auto_exit 1 --no_overwrite 1 -y upconv_7_anime_style_art_rgb -o "C:\Users\Christian\workspace\CodeLyokoUpscaleing\bin\1440Frames"
```

I really think it should work as I converted it from another batch file I created that contained variables instead of file paths

```
waifu2x-caffe-cui -i "%~dp0480Frames" -e png -l png -m noise_scale -d 16 -h 1440 -n 1 -p cudnn -c 256 -o "%~dp01440Frames" --auto_start 1 --auto_exit 1 --no_overwrite 1 -y upconv_7_anime_style_art_rgb
```

But I still get the weird output.
How can I see what the error is?

Comment: This works for me nicely: `waifu2x-caffe-cui -i "folder" --gpu 0 --crop_size 512 -d 16 -p cudnn -s 2.0 -n 1 -m noise_scale -e png -l png -b 1 -y upconv_7_anime_style_art_rgb -o "folder2"`. I changed the parameters a bit, though.